# While loop - Counter being updated when anything other than y/n are entered

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, counter

I would like to know a simple way to NOT update the counter, within a while loop, when something other than y/n is entered. Here is my code:

```
if yes_or_no == "y":                                                        
    computer_winnings += 1                                                  
elif yes_or_no == "n":                                                      
    user_winnings += 1                                                      
counter += 1                                                                
if counter > 10:                                                            
    break
```

However, main `counter` is also being updated if user enters anything other than y/n. Counter should only update if `y` or `n` was entered.

Comment: Just put `counter += 1` within the relevent `if` / `elif` statements.

Comment: Thank you! Here is how I fixed it:
27     if yes_or_no == "y":                                                        
 28         counter += 1                                                                             
 30     elif yes_or_no == "n":                                                      
 31         counter += 1
 33     else:             
 34         print("Please enter y or n ONLY!")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the counter increment under a test for either `y` or `n`

```
if yes_or_no in ('y', 'n'):
    counter += 1
    if yes_or_no == 'y':
        computer_winnings += 1
    else:
        user_winnings += 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Here is how I fixed it:
 27     if yes_or_no == "y":                                                        
 28         counter += 1                                                                           
 30     elif yes_or_no == "n":                                                      
 31         counter += 1                                                                                       
 33     else:                                                                       
 34         print("Please enter y or n ONLY!")

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we iterate from 0 to 9

```
i = 0
while(i < 10):
    #Ask for user input
    foo = input()
    #if foo value != yes_or_no value increment i
    if foo != yes_or_no:
        i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent codes properly to fall under whatever statement you wish it to be in. How you have it written the if/else are 1 independent set, the counter is also an independent set, and the if counter state is also independent. So you have 3 independent statements running at the same time.

And with if statements your code will only process them once and only once, so using a while loop would be best to loop continuously until you hit an escape statement.